# How to show default location indicator on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Is there any way to show default blue indicator for current location on MKMapView like in standard Map application on iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, click on the MKMapView and click the "User Location" checkbox.

Programatically:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

As user3870739 wrote, you have to set showUserLocation to true.

Additionally you must make sure, that the user location is in the visible area of the map:

```
let userLocation = mapView.userLocation

if userLocation.location != nil{
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
       userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

And, of course, you have to ask for permission to get the location before:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //ask for location authorizaion
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    return true
}
```